# Flutter : How can use String data outside future method?

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I have this future method to get a data from server and using it :

```
 Future<String> get_week() async {
      var weekUrl =
          'https://xxx/api/controller/matchs/active_week.php';
      var weekresponse = await http.get(weekUrl);
      var weekdata = await jsonDecode(weekresponse.body);
      var weekId = weekdata[0]['w_id'];
      return weeId
    }
```

How can i use the value of weekId outside this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `await` keyword to assign the returned value from the future to variable:

```
String id = await get_week();
```

Comment: Thanks ,but where outside the method i use the await? anywhere it will ask async

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do with the data

Comment: thanks i put it in onpressed the button and it is work